# Neural Network and Binary classification Guidance

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I have the following data (X) that is stored in a numpy array:

```
array([[ 0.82737724, -0.5924806 ,  0.43279337, ...,  0.91896631,
        -0.28188124,  0.58595414],
       [-1.56610693,  0.63878901,  0.43279337, ...,  1.28262456,
         1.16154512, -1.9423032 ],
       [ 0.82737724, -0.2846632 , -0.4745452 , ...,  1.64628282,
        -0.28188124,  0.58595414],
       ...,
       [ 0.82737724,  0.        ,  0.43279337, ...,  1.67617254,
        -0.28188124,  0.58595414],
       [-1.56610693, -0.2846632 , -0.4745452 , ..., -1.64656796,
         0.27001707, -1.9423032 ],
       [ 0.82737724,  0.17706291, -0.4745452 , ...,  0.63501397,
        -0.28188124, -0.67817453]])
```

The array is much larger, and it gets fed into this neural network:

```
def base_model1():
    input_dim = X.shape[1]
    output_dim = 1
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(10, input_dim= input_dim,kernel_initializer ='normal', activation= 'tanh'))
    model.add(Dense(1, input_dim = 100, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['MeanSquaredError',
        'AUC',])
    
    return model
NN_clf = KerasClassifier(build_fn=base_model1, epochs=100, verbose=1)
NN_clf._estimator_type = "classifier"
trained = NN_clf.fit(X,y.values.reshape(-1,1))
```

Y is binary ones and zeroes. Where 1 means that will ride a taxi or 0 that will not ride a taxi.

```
predictions1 = trained.model.predict(X_test, verbose=1)
predictions1[:5]
array([[0.09048176],
       [0.34411064],
       [0.08842686],
       [0.0986585 ],
       [0.58971184]], dtype=float32)
```

My question stems from here if Sigmoid is an activation layer that performs binary classification or these probability outputs? Because I was expecting 1's and 0's I eventually assuming that these are probability outputs I created the following:

```
blank = []
for i in pd.DataFrame(predictions1)[0].to_list():
    if i > .50:
        blank.append(1)
    else:
        blank.append(0)
```

Much of my confusion lies in binary classification how does a neural network handle them, and how does one get 1's and 0's.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you pass some `input` for prediction to your binary classifier (`sigmoid` activation in its last layer), it will give you matrices in which each row represents the **probability of those inputs** to be in `class 1`. In your case:

```
predictions1 = trained.model.predict(X_test, verbose=1)
predictions1[:5]
array([[0.09048176],
       [0.34411064],
       [0.08842686],
       [0.0986585 ],
       [0.58971184]],
```

Here, each score represents the possibility of each sample in `X_test[:5]` to be in `class 1`. From this point, in order to get class labels (e.g. `1` and `0`), by default API uses the `0.5` threshold to consider each score belong to `class 1` and `class 0`; more specifically, score greater than `0.5` are considered to `class 1`. But of course, we can tweak the threshold. Here is one dummy example

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np  

img = tf.random.normal([20, 32], 0, 1, tf.float32)
tar = np.random.randint(2, size=(20, 1))

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, input_dim = 32, 
                       kernel_initializer ='normal', activation= 'relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

```
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', 
              optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(img, tar, epochs=5, verbose=2)

Epoch 1/5
1/1 - 0s - loss: 0.7058 - accuracy: 0.5500
Epoch 2/5
1/1 - 0s - loss: 0.6961 - accuracy: 0.5500
Epoch 3/5
1/1 - 0s - loss: 0.6869 - accuracy: 0.5500
Epoch 4/5
1/1 - 0s - loss: 0.6779 - accuracy: 0.6000
Epoch 5/5
1/1 - 0s - loss: 0.6692 - accuracy: 0.6000
```

**Probabilities**

```
y_pred = model.predict(img)
print(y_pred.shape)
y_pred[:10]

(20, 1)
array([[0.5317636 ],
       [0.4592613 ],
       [0.5876541 ],
       [0.47071406],
       [0.56284094],
       [0.5025074 ],
       [0.46471453],
       [0.38649547],
       [0.43361676],
       [0.4667967 ]], dtype=float32)
```

**Class labels**

```
(model.predict(img) > 0.5).astype("int32")
array([[1],
       [0],
       [1],
       [0],
       [1],
       [1],
       [0],
       [0],
       [0],
       [0],
       [0],
....
....
```