# AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute 'predict_proba'

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

predict_proba returns the error in the neural network

i saw the example on this link https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-make-classification-and-regression-predictions-for-deep-learning-models-in-keras/

https://faroit.com/keras-docs/1.0.0/models/sequential/#the-sequential-model-api

I am using Tensorflow Version: 2.6.0

**Code:**

```
#creating the object (Initializing the ANN)
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
LAYERS = [
         tf.keras.layers.Dense(50, activation="relu", input_shape=X_train.shape[1:]),
         tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(),
         tf.keras.layers.Dense(25, activation="relu"),
         tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="relu"),
         tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation="relu"),
         tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
         tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
]

LOSS = "binary_crossentropy"
OPTIMIZER = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-3)

model_cEXT = tf.keras.models.Sequential(LAYERS)
model_cEXT.compile(loss=LOSS , optimizer=OPTIMIZER, metrics=['accuracy'])

EPOCHS = 100

checkpoint_cb = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint("model_cEXT.h5", save_best_only=True)
early_stopping_cb = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=10, restore_best_weights=True)
tensorboard_cb = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir="logs")
CALLBACKS = [checkpoint_cb, early_stopping_cb, tensorboard_cb]

model_cEXT.fit(X_train, y_train['cEXT'], epochs = EPOCHS, validation_data=(X_test, y_test['cEXT']), callbacks = CALLBACKS)

model_cEXT.predict_proba(X_test)
```

**Error:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-72-8f06353cf345> in <module>()
----> 1 model_cEXT.predict_proba(X_test)

AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute 'predict_proba'
```

**Edit:**
i need sklearn's like predict_proba output it is needed for visualization

```
skplt.metrics.plot_precision_recall_curve(y_test['cEXT'].values, y_prob)
plt.title('Precision-Recall Curve - cEXT')
plt.show()
```

Comment: _What is your question_? The error is clear. Tensorflow is not scikit-learn.

Comment: wants to print probability like scikit-learn's predict_proba

Comment: but i saw the example on deep learning too https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-make-classification-and-regression-predictions-for-deep-learning-models-in-keras/

Comment: @JunedAnsari `predict_proba` is deprecated. Instead, simply use `predict` to get the probabilities. See my answer here for more details and let me know if it helps. https://stackoverflow.com/a/67467084/9215780

Comment: Huh, my apologies. I wasn't aware old keras versions had this method.

Answer (score 6):

Use this code instead

```
predict_prob=model.predict([testa,testb])

predict_classes=np.argmax(predict_prob,axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

New Version might not have predict_proba method so i have creadted my own using .predict method

```
def predict_prob(number):
  return [number[0],1-number[0]]

y_prob = np.array(list(map(predict_prob, model_cEXT.predict(X_test))))
y_prob
```

Comment: Note, It's NOT the solution. The `mode. predict` already gives the probabilities.  The new version is more precise. In your above code snippet, it doesn't make sense to compute twice the probabilities of the same class.

Comment: @M.Innat, i know it returns probability, but if you compare it with sklearns predict_prob you will see the difference. sklearns prdict_prob will return two output like true class probability and the false class probability it was needed for the visualization skplt.metrics.plot_precision_recall_curve