# Unable to load keras model with custom layers

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have trained a [keras](/questions/tagged/keras) model with a custom layer. The model trains perfectly fine and gets stored. But when I am trying to load the model, I am unable to load it. Below is the code from the custom class:

```
from keras.engine.base_layer import Layer

class AttentionLayer(Layer):
  def __init__(self, attention_dim, **kwargs):
    super(AttentionLayer, self).__init__(name="attention_layer")
    self.init = initializers.get("normal")
    self.supports_masking = True
    self.attention_dim = attention_dim
    super(AttentionLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

  def get_config(self):
    config = {
      "init": self.init,
      "supports_masking": self.supports_masking,
      "attention_dim": self.attention_dim,
    }

    base_config = super(AttentionLayer, self).get_config()
    return dict(list(base_config.items()) + list(config.items()))
```

I then try to load the model in the following way:

```
model = keras.models.load_model("model.h5", 
                custom_objects={"AttentionLayer": AttentionLayer})
```

But I keep getting

```
ValueError: Unknown config_item: RandomNormal. Please ensure this object is passed to the 'custom_objects' argument.
```

Almost all the questions that I referred to on StackOverflow suggested the same, but unfortunately, it is not working in my case. Could someone point out if I am making any mistake?

The link to my colab is [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1-_1HYf5lZ8I8Vel6BLGugFOntYKniUcG?usp=sharing).

Comment: Try `custom_objects={'attention_layer':AttentionLayer} as your layer name is `attention_layer`

Comment: @AhmadAnis that also does not work, have already tried it.

Comment: What is your tensorflow version?

Comment: @AhmadAnis `tf==2.6.0` and `keras==2.6.0`.

Comment: try: `from tensorflow.keras.engine.base_layer ..`. and initializers

Comment: Try downgrading to 2.2.0 or 2.0.0, and rerun, and resave, and reload the model.

Comment: @AhmadAnis downgrading to `v2.0.0` causes my tokenizer to break and with `tf==2.2.0` keras breaks.

Comment: @M.Innat with `tf==2.6.0` I tried to update the layer import to `tensorflow.keras.layers import Layer`, while the one you suggested says `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.keras.engine_base_layer'`.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible code? a colab link would be ok.

Comment: @M.Innat please find the link to Colab `https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1-_1HYf5lZ8I8Vel6BLGugFOntYKniUcG?usp=sharing`

Comment: Please share the publicly shared files, the above link needs owner acceptance.

Comment: @M.Innat please try again as I have updated the settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried to resolve your issue. But before that here's one thing I want you to look at

```
preds = Dense(2, activation="softmax")(l_att_sent)
model = Model(review_input, preds)
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", 
              optimizer="rmsprop", metrics=["accuracy"])
```

If you set `(..2, activations='softmax')`, normally you should use `categorical_cross_entropy` and corresponding metrics (above metric is ok as you have used **string identifier**). But I saw that you've used `binary_crossentropy` as loss function, so I assumed that you probably need as follows in your last layer: `(..1, activations='sigmoid')`. Here is some reference for that: a). [Selecting loss and metrics for the Tensorflow model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67848962/selecting-loss-and-metrics-for-tensorflow-model/67851641#67851641). b). [Neural Network and Binary classification Guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67467084/9215780).

---

In your code, I think the problem comes by using the `"init": self.init,` in `get_config` method; you don't need to anyway.

```
from tensorflow.keras import initializers
self.init = initializers.get("normal")
```

---

For future reference, here is the working code end-to-end.

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
from tensorflow.keras import initializers
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.layers import (Embedding, Dense, Input, GRU,
                                     Bidirectional, TimeDistributed)
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
```

```
class AttentionLayer(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, attention_dim, supports_masking=True, **kwargs):
        super(AttentionLayer, self).__init__(name="attention_layer")
        self.init = initializers.get("normal")
        self.supports_masking = supports_masking
        self.attention_dim = attention_dim
        super(AttentionLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        assert len(input_shape) == 3
        self.W = K.variable(self.init((input_shape[-1], self.attention_dim)), name="W")
        self.b = K.variable(self.init((self.attention_dim, )), name="b")
        self.u = K.variable(self.init((self.attention_dim, 1)), name="u")
        self._trainable_weights = [self.W, self.b, self.u]
        super(AttentionLayer, self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, x, mask=None):
        uit = K.tanh(K.bias_add(K.dot(x, self.W), self.b))
        ait = K.dot(uit, self.u)
        ait = K.squeeze(ait, -1)
        ait = K.exp(ait)

        if mask is not None:
            ait *= K.cast(mask, K.floatx())

        ait /= K.cast(K.sum(ait, axis=1, keepdims=True) + K.epsilon(), K.floatx())
        ait = K.expand_dims(ait)
        weighted_input = x * ait
        output = K.sum(weighted_input, axis=1)
        return output

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return (input_shape[0], input_shape[-1])

    def get_config(self):
        config = {
            "supports_masking": self.supports_masking,
            "attention_dim": self.attention_dim,
        }
        base_config = super(AttentionLayer, self).get_config()
        return dict(list(base_config.items()) + list(config.items()))
```

```
MAX_SENTENCE_LEN = 10
MAX_SENTENCES = 15
MAX_NUM_WORDS = 200
EMBEDDING_DIM = 10
VALIDATION_SPLIT = 0.2

# we use Embedding layer to convert positive integers into dense vectors of
# fixed size
embedding_layer = Embedding(
  100,
  EMBEDDING_DIM,
  input_length=MAX_SENTENCE_LEN,
  trainable=True,
  mask_zero=True
)
```

```
sentence_input = Input(shape=(MAX_SENTENCE_LEN, ), dtype="int32")
embedded_sequences = embedding_layer(sentence_input)
l_lstm = Bidirectional(GRU(100, return_sequences=True))(embedded_sequences)
l_att = AttentionLayer(100)(l_lstm)
sentEncoder = Model(sentence_input, l_att)
sentEncoder.summary() # OK
```

```
review_input = Input(shape=(MAX_SENTENCES, MAX_SENTENCE_LEN), dtype="int32")
review_encoder = TimeDistributed(sentEncoder)(review_input)
l_lstm_sent = Bidirectional(GRU(100, return_sequences=True))(review_encoder)
l_att_sent = AttentionLayer(100)(l_lstm_sent)
preds = Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(l_att_sent)
model = Model(review_input, preds)
model.summary() # OK
```

**DummyData**

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np  

x_train = np.random.randint(0, 10, (100,15,10)); print(x_train.shape)
y_train = np.random.randint(2, size=(100, 1)); print(y_train.shape)
(100, 15, 10)
(100, 1)
```

**Train**

```
filepath = "model.h5"
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer="rmsprop", 
              metrics=["accuracy"])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=2, verbose=2)
model.save(filepath)

Epoch 1/2
142ms/step - loss: 0.6964 - accuracy: 0.4100
Epoch 2/2
144ms/step - loss: 0.5919 - accuracy: 0.5500
```

**Reload and Check**

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
new_model = load_model(filepath, 
                       custom_objects={"AttentionLayer": AttentionLayer})

# Let's check:
np.testing.assert_allclose(
    model.predict(x_train), new_model.predict(x_train)
) # OK
```

[Colab.](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1-_1HYf5lZ8I8Vel6BLGugFOntYKniUcG?usp=sharing)