# when predict the 2nd label has high score

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm trying to set a custom binary classification model in `tensorflow` and the frame of this model looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHF9X.png)
when I am training this model on the dataset, it all goes right; ([Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8d2X.png)). But when I try to evaluate or predict it goes wrong and it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jL1t5.png)
all the predicted results of this dataset have high score on the 2nd label and I don't know why. Here's the code:

```
def getModel():
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(64, 64)),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax')
    ])

    model.summary()
    lossFn = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
    initial_learning_rate = 0.3
    decay_steps = 1.0
    decay_rate = 0.5
    # learning_rate_fn = tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.InverseTimeDecay(initial_learning_rate, decay_steps, decay_rate)

    model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(),
                  loss=lossFn,
                  metrics='accuracy')

    return model


def getDataset(path):
    with np.load(path) as data:
        trainData = data['img']
        # trainData = np.reshape(trainData, (trainData.shape[0], trainData.shape[1], trainData.shape[2]))
        trainLabels = data['label']
    trainSet = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((trainData, trainLabels))
    trainSet = trainSet.batch(BATCH_SIZE)

    return trainSet


def getTestSet(path):
    with np.load(path) as data:
        testData = data['img']
        # testData = np.reshape(testData, (testData.shape[0], testData.shape[1], testData.shape[2]))
        testLabels = data['label']
    testSet = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((testData, testLabels))
    testSet = testSet.batch(BATCH_SIZE)

    return testSet


def getAcc(history):
    plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'], label='accuracy')
    # plt.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'], label = 'val_accuracy')

    plt.xlabel('Epoch')
    plt.ylabel('acc')
    plt.legend(loc='lower right')
    plt.savefig('./acc.png')
    plt.clf()


def getLoss(history):
    plt.plot(history.history['loss'], label='loss')
    plt.xlabel('Epoch')
    plt.ylabel('loss')
    plt.legend(loc='lower right')
    plt.savefig('./loss.png')


if __name__ == "__main__": model = getModel()
    dataset = getDataset('./train.npz')
    checkpoint_path = "training_1/cp.ckpt"
    checkpoint_dir = os.path.dirname(checkpoint_path)
    cp_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath=checkpoint_path,
                                                 save_weights_only=True,
                                                 verbose=1)
    history = model.fit(dataset, epochs=5, callbacks=[cp_callback])
    getAcc(history)
    getLoss(history)
    model.save('GRaymodel.h5')
    print('training done!!')
    test = getTestSet('test.npz')
    loss, acc = model.evaluate(test)
    print(model.predict(test))
    print('Restored model, accuracy: {:5.2f}%'.format(100 * acc))
```

Comment: What is the distribution of your data? is it a balanced dataset? How many samples fall into categories A & B? I think you overfitted the model on Category A.

Comment: I can see many issue, (1) you said binary but you use loss function that is used in multi-class. (2). you set `from_logit=True` but `activations` of your last layer is not `None` but you set `softmax`. See this answer, [(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67467084/9215780), [(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67851641/9215780)

Comment: @Innat thx bro. i am a noob on DP so there're lots of mistakes ,anyway thx

Comment: @Amir A & B are half to half ,so probably problems are on my model

Comment: @Innat I try to fix it today but failed, as u say i used `sigmoid` and i change lossFn as binary_crossentropy. but the problem is still here, all the data detected to ones

Answer (score 0):

This model is working absolutely fine. You just need to remove the `softmax` activation function from the **getModel()** as `SparseCategoricalCrossentropy()` loss will automatically calculate the logits of the dataset when it sets 'True' and will encode the label into a probability distribution. So you may need to use `argmax()` to convert these probabilities to find exact index of the predicted label while model prediction.

Please use the below code for the model prediction:(Please find the relevent  [gist](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/RenuPatelGoogle/881c502d1aaa26da6ff19e59564ff205/75458297.ipynb#scrollTo=sDwKbZuzJVPj) here for your reference)

```
print('\nModel prediction!')
with np.load(path) as data:
    testData = data['x_test']
    # testData = np.reshape(testData, (testData.shape[0], testData.shape[1], testData.shape[2]))
    testLabels = data['y_test']
pred = model.predict(testData)
print("Predicted Value:", np.argmax(pred[5]))

print("Actual Value:", testLabels[5])
```

Output:

```
Model prediction!
313/313 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step
Predicted Value: 1
Actual Value: 1
```